# Abstract Type Initialization using Initializer list in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

I started reading the book 'The C++ Programming Language - 4th Edition' by Bjarne Struoustrup and found the following example bit confusing (Abstract Types - page 66):

```
class Container {
public:
    virtual double& operator[](int) = 0; // pure virtual function
    virtual int size() const = 0; // const member function (§3.2.1.1)
    virtual ~Container() {} // destructor (§3.2.1.2)
};

class Vector_container : public Container { // Vector_container implements Container
Vector v;
public:
    Vector_container(int s) : v(s) { } // Vector of s elements
    ~Vector_container() {}
    double& operator[](int i) { return v[i]; }
    int size() const { return v.size(); }
};
```

Client code:

```
void use(Container& c)
{
    const int sz = c.size();
    for (int i=0; i!=sz; ++i)
    cout << c[i] << '\n';
}

void g()
{
    Vector_container vc {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    use(vc);
}
```

Are we not missing the following constructor in the class declaration of Vector_container?

```
Vector_container(std::initializer_list<double> s) : v(s) { } // Vector of s elements
```

Please correct me if I misunderstood anything here.

Comment: Is there an errata for the book?

Comment: There is exactly one erratum online for the 4th edition (http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html). Somebody could direct Bjarne's attention to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we not missing the following constructor in the class declaration
>   of Vector_container?
>
> ```
> Vector_container(std::initializer_list<double> s) : v(s) { } // Vector of s elements
> ```

Of course you're right.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/EBX76765)

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of
>   'Vector_container'
>       Vector_container vc {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

[LIVE with ctor taking initializer_list as parameter](http://rextester.com/AIRGZ92021)